# How to remove image fringe with opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv

There is some technique using python + OpenCV to remove the fringes of an image?

For example, for this input:

[image]

I want to get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Flood fill the background with black
- Make the non-black regions white and save as mask
- Erode the mask to inside the dark outer region of the input
- Use the mask to make the image white where the mask is black
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('food.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# floodfill background with black
floodfill = cv2.floodFill(img, mask, (0,0), (0,0,0), (30), (0), flags=8)[1]

# make all other colors but black into white
mask = floodfill.copy()
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask[mask!=0] = 255

# erode mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (40,40))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# use mask to change background to white
result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = 255

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('food_floodfilled.jpg',floodfill)
cv2.imwrite('food_mask.jpg',mask)
cv2.imwrite('food_processed.jpg',result)

# show the images
#cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("floodfill", floodfill)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Floodfilled image:

[image]

Mask image after erosion:

[image]

Result:

[image]